# Why is inserting multiple elements into a std::set simultaneously faster?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I'm reading through:

> "The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference by Nicolai M.
>   Josuttis"

and I'm in the section about Sets & Multisets. I came across a line regarding Inserting and Removing elements:

> "Inserting and removing happens faster if, when working with multiple
>   elements, you use a single call for all elements rather than multiple
>   calls."

I'm far from a data structures master, but I'm aware that they're implemented with red-black trees.  What I don't understand from that is how would the STL implementers write an algorithm to insert multiple elements at once in a faster manner?

Can anyone shed some light on why this quote is true for me?

Comment: Doesn't it state that it's just because `you use a single call for all elements rather than multiple calls.`

Comment: @Shahbaz: not at all, it states it's faster when you use a single call but gives no reason.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah sorry! I **imagined** a _because_ before that sentence (This shows I am tired, maybe I should stop coding for today)

Comment: It's okay, I know the feeling. I had to delete 2 answers from last night because I tried to SO from my phone on a train after a 14 hour work day - it wasn't my best work to say the least :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought was that it might rebalance the tree only after inserting/erasing the whole range. Since the whole operation is inlined in practice, that seems more likely than the number of function calls.

Checking the GCC headers on my local machine, this doesn't seem to be the case - and anyway, I don't know how the tradeoff between reduced rebalancing activity, and potentially increased search times for intermediate inserts to an unbalanced tree, would work out.

Maybe it's considered a QoI issue, but in any case, using the *most expressive* method is probably best, not just because it saves you writing a `for` loop and shows your intention most clearly, but because it leaves library writers latitude to optimise more aggressively in the future, without you needing to know and change your code.

Comment: It actually did cross my mind that you might be able to do a mass-insert with only one rebalance.  I wasn't sure if you could properly rebalance a tree after a mass insert without just as much work though.  Do you think rebalancing after the fact would be faster than rebalancing on each insert?

Comment: In some cases you can insert them into the correct positions and not do _any_ balancing (inserting into empty set for example, or if all new nodes are leaves on the same level), but those require balancing to be off for each individual insert.  (Unless you're _way_ craftier than I am)

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons:

1) Making a single call for multiple elements instead of N times more calls.

2) The insertion operation checks for each element inserted whether another element exists already in the container with the same value. This can be optimized when insterting multiple elements together.

Comment: 1) Is not necessarily faster, templates call tend to be inlined so if the insertion only loops through elements, you gain nothing. 2) I think the goal of the question is to understand the optimization. If the elements to be inserted were sorted, I would understand the performance gain, but since they are not I admit I wonder what kind of optimization can be applied.

Comment: For 1), try comparing assembly outputs before trusting your favorite C++ compiler. :) For 2), i have some optimizations in mind but i don't know which optimization STL uses. i just thought if i know how to optimize it, creators of STL should know better, right?

Comment: Perhaps you could include some of the optimizations you have in mind in your answer? I think, like @MatthieuM., that this would be more constructive than just saying that there could be optimizations.

Comment: @EmirAkaydın: I don't trust my compiler, I simply throw Callgrind at the problem when I am having performance issues to identify the hotspots :) and generally just avoid premature pessimization which is sufficient most of the times.

Comment: One of the most simple optimization can be not trying to insert the same value twice in the set. If you try to insert the same value over and over again in different calls, you need to search for uniqueness each time you try to insert. But if you do this in one pass, you have a chance to cache, at least the last insterted value. if you think this can even decrease the performance in some cases like trying to insert already unique values, i'm sure this can be overcomed by using free cycles left from individual calls. And again, that's my assumption, not how STL works. But it can be optimized.

Comment: But what you are describing might just as well turn out to be a pessimization if I'm not inserting duplicates.

Comment: @UncleBens: I thought I already mentioned that in my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you read as you quoted is wrong. Inserting to a `std::set` is O(log n), unless you use the `insert()` overload with the position iterator, in which case it is *amortized* O(n) when the position is valid. **But**, if you use the range overload with *sorted* elements *then* you get O(n) insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management could be a good reason. In this case it could allocate the memory just once. If all elements are called separatelly, all calls try allocate memory separatelly. As I know, most of the `set` and `map` implementations try to keep the memory in the same page, or pages near together to minimalize page faults.

Comment: It can't allocate them as an array though (for speed) since it may need to deallocate them at different times.  How would `set`/`map` try to keep memory on the same page without custom allocators?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about this, but I think that if the number of elements inserted is smaller than the number of elements in the set, then it can be more efficient to sort the inserted range before performing the insertions. This way, all values can be inserted in a single pass over the tree, and duplicates in the inserted range can be easily eliminated (or inserted very fast in the case of a multiset).

Of course, this optimization is only possible if the input iterators allows sorting the input range (i.e. if they are random iterators).

Comment: The standard says each element in `[i,j)` we be dereferenced at most once, so sorting is out of  the question.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, right, I forgot that `InputIterator`s only allowed single pass algorithms.

Comment: However, are you sure this restriction applies to all specializations? I mean, if an algorithm is specialized for a given concept of iterators (say `RandomIterator`), why should this specialization be restricted by requirements on other iterator concepts? For example, both `std::distance` and `std::advance` work on `InputIterator`s, but they are specialized for `RandomIterator` and applies `operator-` and `operator+`, which are not supported by `InputIterator`s.

Comment: The standard says that about the _containers_, not about the iterators.  A standard-conforming container may not dereference any element more than once.  I suppose it could make a copy though, and sort that...

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't get your point: firstly, what do you mean by "A container may not dereference any element more than once"? Do you mean container's member functions (and their constructors)? Could you point to the paragraph you are reffering to so that I can understand better? Secondly, if this what the standard says, I don't understand what is the rationale behind this decision. Why prevent an implementation from providing optimized implementations of certain member functions for some particular inputs?

Comment: `§ 23.2.3/4 [sequence.reqmts]` in the requirements for expressions `X(i, j)` and `X a(i, j)`: `Requires: ...Each iterator in the
range [i,j) shall be dereferenced exactly once.`.  Also the expression `a.insert(p,i,j)`: `Requires: ...Each iterator in the
range [i,j) shall be dereferenced exactly once.`.  I have absolutely no idea why it requires that.  It's a completely arbitrary limitation as far as I can tell.

Comment: Perhaps so you can pass an input iterator (eg. one which reads from an ifstream)?