# why inserting into set with same amount has different runtimes based on different approaches?

Tags: c++, data-structures, insert, set

I am writing a parallel program that generates combinations as a boolean vector form. Since the combinations are generated using threads, I am combining them when every thread finishes its job.

```
set<vector<bool>> Ci[T.size()];
//generate combinations in parallel and thread i add result in Ci[i]

start_time = omp_get_wtime();
set<vector<bool>> C;
for(int i=0;i<T.size();i++){
    cout << "i=" << i << "\t" << Ci[i].size() << endl;
    C.insert(Ci[i].begin(),Ci[i].end());//here combine them into a single set
}
end_time = omp_get_wtime();
total_time = end_time - start_time;
cout << " Total time:" <<total_time << endl;
cout <<  C.size();
```

The total number of threads, T.size() will vary but total combination(C's size) is always the same. 
For example,

```
Enter threads:10
i=0 1
i=1 144
i=2 4320
i=3 47040
i=4 229320
i=5 550368
i=6 672672
i=7 411840
i=8 115830
i=9 11440
Total time:36.641s
C's size :2042975

Enter threads:128
i=0 9
i=1 45
i=2 165
...
i=120   10
i=121   11
i=122   12
i=123   13
i=124   14
i=125   15
i=126   16
i=127   18
Total time:6.432s
C's size :2042975
```

What I don't understand is in both case, I am inserting the same amount of combinations into C. Why is the time taken not the same?

Comment: The size is not the same... seems like there's a lot of more work when i runs from `0...9` Though the size at the end is the same, so perhaps inserting in smaller chunks is faster. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170202/why-is-inserting-multiple-elements-into-a-stdset-simultaneously-faster) can help?

Comment: The size is the same... I am just leaving out the values from i=3 to i=119. For example, when i=12 203490 , i=15 477445. It is just that the values are not equally distributed.

Comment: I was thinking like that too. So, I test with different C size and number of threads.

When C size is 53130
if the number of threads is 126 -> total time is 0.667s.
if the number of threads is 80 -> total time is 0.148s.
In this case, the situation is reversed.

Comment: More threads doesn't always mean faster. Creating a thread also has an overhead. (For the second case).

Comment: Yes. I agree. But thread related stuffs are not included in calculating runtime. Combining results from threads is done sequentially. Based on the threads, Ci's size changes. That is all related to threads.

Comment: Please try to distill the code into a [mcve] and provide the compiler command (did you make sure to compile with optimization?) as well as some system information. This may very well have nothing to do with the parallelism, but only with the shape of the input data.

Comment: You're inserting a lot of elements which are already in order. Maybe it triggers some edge case, as the underlying structure (RB-tree) needs to do more work to keep the tree balanced. If you have less threads, then the number of elements which are already in order is more, that's why you get less performance. This is just speculation, but seems a sensible explanation for me. Just for fun, you may try to put all elements into a vector first, then shuffle it, and then put it into the set.

Comment: @geza Your idea is absolutely right. In my program, the algorithm is different based on the number of threads. (here I will use numbers for each combination to be simple)In the threads 10 case, results are like if i=1 ->{1,2,3}, i=2 ->{4,5,6} so, combining them is simple {1,2,3,4,5,6 ....}. But in the threads 128 case, results are like if i=1 ->{1,3,5}, i=2->{2,4,6} so, combining them takes more time. I don't need results to be sorted. So, I guess I will change from using set to vector.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your observation on my system (Windows/mingw). I tried putting 2M distinct binary vectors of size 30 into the T sets  `Ci` and then run your code (except I use C++ `chrono` for time measurements, which should have no impact). For T=10, the time is 1.991 s. For T=128 it is 2.919 s. As far as I understand this is the opposite of your result.

Comment: @nielsen It might be because the difference between how are these elements distributed among them. If you want to test, https://ideone.com/TRWvuk -> for this program, input is(25 9 10) which means choose 9 objects out of 25 objects and run on 10 threads. Combining the results happens in line 44 to 49. https://ideone.com/RT4ROR -> for this program, input is(25 9 128) which means choose 9 objects out of 25 objects and run on 128 threads. Combining the results happens in line 79 to 85.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't see all the necessary information, but I suspect the problem is caused by the uneven distribution of set sizes. The complexity of the insertion is *O(n log(m + n))*, where *n* is the size of a set being inserted into (`C`) and *m* is the size of the set being inserted (`Ci[i]`).

Now, consider that both sets together have 2^24 elements.

**Case 1: *n=2^16*, *m=2^24-2^16***

Here, the term inside "big O" is turned into *2^16 * log(2^24-2^16+2^16)*, which is *2^16*24*.

**Case 2: *n=2^23*, *m=2^23***

Here, the same term is *2^23*24*, which is ***2^7* times more** than in Case 1.

My point is that if you "merge" two sets with the **same total number of elements**, the runtime may very much depend on how are these elements distributed among them.

In your first case (10 threads), the distribution of set sizes seems to be more like in Case 2 (most of them have a relatively high number of elements). We don't see the complete data for your second case (128 threads), but the set sizes seem to be much more unevenly distributed since the shown ones have only very few elements. (*Note that it may, or may not, indicate that your parallel computation is poorly load balanced.*)

Comment: You are right especially the part "if you merge two sets with the same total number of elements, the runtime may very much depend on how are these elements distributed among them. "

Comment: @Daniel Langr: my apologies, I had a misconception in mind when writing my comment - I have deleted it to avoid future confusion. However, your calculation has the problem that it considers insertion of a large set into an existing set (case 1) vs a small set into an existing set (case 2). Clearly, inserting the small set is cheaper. Continues...

Comment: A more reasonable comparison would be to consider insertion of two sets which combined has the same size into an existing set. If the existing set is empty (it does not matter for the conclusion), then case 1 (size 2^24-2^16 and size 2^16) would give approximately (2^24-2^16)*24+2^16*24 = 2^24*24. Case 2 (size 2^23 and 2^23) would give approximately 2^23*23+2^23*24. I.e. roughly the same.

Comment: @nilsen I don't think we can evaluate the _reasonability_ of comparisons here, since we don't know the OP's data in detail. I just wanted to point out to one possible cause. Generally, even when you "merge" two sets of exact same sizes, the runtime might differ considerably based on actual data. Some illustrative (corner-case) experiment is here: http://quick-bench.com/aqcxm42XPw16O2VL93NEvLKoWAk.

Comment: @Daniel Langr As I read it the OP is starting out with an empty set `C` and inserts two different sets of sets into it. The two sets of sets have in common that their combined size is the same. All I am saying is that your answer addresses a different situation of combining (only) two sets by merging one into the other. In this case it is not very surprising that if the second set is 2^7 times larger than the first, then the same is the run time.

Comment: @nielsen There are no _two different sets of sets_ is OP's code. There is just the array of sets `Ci`. The sets `Ci[i]` are combined into `C`. In the first case, there are 10 sets being combined and most of their sizes are relatively high (up to 672,672). In the second case, there are 128 sets and _we don't know sizes of all of them_, only of very few, which are actually extremally small (9, 45, ..., 16, 18). Of course that exact numbers in my question does not match accurately. How could they, if I don't know all the data.

Comment: @nielsen The purpose of my answer was to address a _possible_ cause of the problem. Without all the data, no one can answer it for sure.

Comment: @Daniel Langr One run of the OP's code involves one set of sets. The OP shows two different runs of the code, hence we have two sets of sets, one set of sets for each run of the code. This is my last comment on this subject. I agree that we do not have sufficient information to explain the OP observations.